# Count query within select statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, count

I'm having a minor issue with a tiny mysql query. I'm trying to select a few columns and at the same time count what ever comes out of the table and add the count result as another column. so let's say I have three friends

- friend 1
- friend 2
- friend 3

I want to see another column says allfriends=>3

So I came up with something that look like this

```
SELECT friends.friend, users.avatar, COUNT(*) AS allfriends FROM users,friends
```

now what's that doesn't work. so I tried to group them but then I got a '1' for each row. so it was just count that individual row. My question is: is there a way to count a all the results and add them all together to give me a sum of what ever i retrieved of the tables

Comment: i am so very confuse after reading the question due to the wording, I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.Can you  organize your question or add some examples...?

Comment: I'd suggest using some pseudo-code if you can't word it perfectly, like [no_of_friend = SELECT count(friend) FROM friends] , [no_of_avatar = ....] , [total_count = no_of_friend + no_of_avatar] e.t.c.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've worked more on it. however, I'm trying to select a few columns or rows from two tables. at the same time count as much rows or results come out of the query and put them with the result as another column

Comment: Not sure what your goal is. Is it to get a list of user avatars with a count of their friends? What is the relation between FRINEDS and USERS? If you don't specify join condition you will get a cross-join hence 3*4=12 rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a mysql pro so this is exhasting but helped me learn a lot in the process as well.
here's a sql EXAMPLE that I made with my own DB to demostrate the concept.
i hope this is what you want.

the core concept is to generate a auto_increment column for each table/query results, and then left / right join depends on which table have more rows.
to make a auto increamenting column within 1 SQL is fiddly, what i did is initiate the @cnt variable by

```
(select @cnt := 0 AS rowNumber) as t0
```

but i never used that table. I then do

```
select (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, ....
```

in the following table for the incrmental column.

the method have a critical weakness which is you have to know which column/query will return the most row and predefine the type of JOIN in the SQL. I am not sure if this helps you in any way but I'd like to share it non the less.

```
mysql> select t1.rowNumber,t1.friend, t2.rowNumber,t2.avatar from (select @cnt := 0 AS rowNumber) as t0 RIGHT JOIN (select (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,friend from friends) as t1 using (rowNumber) LEFT JOIN (select @cnt := 0 AS rowNumber) as t4 using (rowNumber) RIGHT JOIN (select (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,avatar from user) as t2 using (rowNumber);
+-----------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| rowNumber |    friend   | rowNumber |   avatar   |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+------------+
|         1 |        0001 |         1 |       0001 |
|         2 |        0002 |         2 |       0002 |
|         3 |        0003 |         3 |       0003 |
|         4 |        0004 |         4 |       0004 |
|         5 |        0005 |         5 |       0005 |
|         6 |        0006 |         6 |       0006 |
|         7 |        0007 |         7 |       0007 |
|         8 |        0008 |         8 |       0008 |
|         9 |        0009 |         9 |       0009 |
|        10 |        0010 |        10 |       0010 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        11 |       0011 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        12 |       0012 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        13 |       0013 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        14 |       0014 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        15 |       0015 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        16 |       0016 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        17 |       0017 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        18 |       0018 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        19 |       0019 |
|      NULL |        NULL |        20 |       0020 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work i think because your question is confusing little bit

SELECT friends.friend, users.avatar,xyz.* FROM users,friends,(SELECT COUNT(*) AS allfriends FROM users,friends)xyz

Comment: i think that might not work, wouldn't it return 12 rows if for example there are 3 friend and 4 avatar ? (3 * 4 = 12)